# Apache HttpClient - REST API: Issue in converting response to customized object which is put as SerializableEntity

Tags: rest, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am using Apache HttpClient to put/get customized object using REST APIs. Below is the sample code. My putObject() method works fine and I could serialize Person object and put properly. However, while getting the object, I got below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to Person    at MyTest.demoGetRESTAPI(MyTest.java:88)    at MyTest.main(MyTest.java:21)
```

Seems the code to build Person object out of response entity is not correct

```
  HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
            byte[] resultByteArray = EntityUtils.toByteArray(httpEntity);
            Person person = (Person)SerializationUtils.deserialize(resultByteArray);
```

Am I doing somthing wrong while getting byte[] array and converting to Person object. Please help me out to solve this issue.

Complete Example Program:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import org.apache.commons.lang.SerializationUtils;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPut;
import org.apache.http.entity.SerializableEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

public class MyTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception  {

        putObject();

        getObject();
    }

    public static void putObject() throws Exception
    {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

       Person person = new Person();
       person.setName("Narendra");
       person.setId("1");

        try
        {
            //Define a postRequest request
            HttpPut putRequest = new HttpPut("http://localhost:9084/ehcache-server/rest/screeningInstance/2221");

            //Set the API media type in http content-type header
            putRequest.addHeader("content-type", "application/x-java-serialized-object");

            //Set the request put body
            SerializableEntity personSEntity = new SerializableEntity(SerializationUtils.serialize(person));
            putRequest.setEntity(personSEntity);

            //Send the request; It will immediately return the response in HttpResponse object if any
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(putRequest);

            //verify the valid error code first
            int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode != 201)
            {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed with HTTP error code : " + statusCode);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            //Important: Close the connect
            httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        }
    }

    public static void getObject() throws Exception
    {
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        try
        {
            //Define a HttpGet request; You can choose between HttpPost, HttpDelete or HttpPut also.
            //Choice depends on type of method you will be invoking.
            HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet("http://localhost:9084/ehcache-server/rest/screeningInstance/2221");

            //Set the API media type in http accept header
            getRequest.addHeader("accept", "application/x-java-serialized-object");

            //Send the request; It will immediately return the response in HttpResponse object
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(getRequest);

            //verify the valid error code first
            int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode != 200)
            {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed with HTTP error code : " + statusCode);
            }

            //Now pull back the response object

            HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
            byte[] resultByteArray = EntityUtils.toByteArray(httpEntity);
            Person person = (Person)SerializationUtils.deserialize(resultByteArray);           
        }
        finally
        {
            //Important: Close the connect
            httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        }
    }

}

class Person implements Serializable{
    String name;
    String id;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person [name=" + name + ", id=" + id + "]";
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution. It was mistake in my code:

While putting object, I have written below code. That was doing two time serialization. First from Person object to byte[] and second from byte[] to byte[].

```
SerializableEntity personSEntity = new SerializableEntity(SerializationUtils.serialize(person));
            putRequest.setEntity(personSEntity);
```

This is the right approach:

```
SerializableEntity personSEntity = new SerializableEntity(person);
            putRequest.setEntity(personSEntity);
```

After getting binary from REST, code should be like below to get Object:

```
HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
InputStream inputStream = null;
try {
         inputStream = httpEntity.getContent(); 
         Person p = (Person) SerializationUtils.deserialize(inputStream);
         System.out.println("Person:" + p.getName());
    }
    finally {
        inputStream.close();
    }
```

This worked like CHARM !!